# Programmatically downloading a file using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was looking for a Chrome Extension which can intercept the download whenever we click on a PDF link or on a link that spawns a PDF at server end programmatically. One way of doing it was Selenium Browser Profiling, I found this particular code. I want Selenium to download the PDF file and rename it according to the strings i pass from the JAVA program.
     How can i use this code to download code and hook it up it with my program. It should trigger this whenever i execute a command like this:-

```
**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,\"/bbtobs/bbtolbext/statements/savepdf?type=current&AccountIndex=0\")]")).click();**


CODE-
package com.lazerycode.selenium.filedownloader;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;

public class FileDownloader {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FileDownloader.class);
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String localDownloadPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    private boolean followRedirects = true;
    private boolean mimicWebDriverCookieState = true;
    private int httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt = 0;

    public FileDownloader(WebDriver driverObject) {
        this.driver = driverObject;
    }

    /**
     * Specify if the FileDownloader class should follow redirects when trying to download a file
     *
     * @param value
     */
    public void followRedirectsWhenDownloading(boolean value) {
        this.followRedirects = value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current location that files will be downloaded to.
     *
     * @return The filepath that the file will be downloaded to.
     */
    public String localDownloadPath() {
        return this.localDownloadPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set the path that files will be downloaded to.
     *
     * @param filePath The filepath that the file will be downloaded to.
     */
    public void localDownloadPath(String filePath) {
        this.localDownloadPath = filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Download the file specified in the href attribute of a WebElement
     *
     * @param element
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String downloadFile(WebElement element) throws Exception {
        return downloader(element, "href");
    }

    /**
     * Download the image specified in the src attribute of a WebElement
     *
     * @param element
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String downloadImage(WebElement element) throws Exception {
        return downloader(element, "src");
    }

    /**
     * Gets the HTTP status code of the last download file attempt
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getHTTPStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt() {
        return this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt;
    }

    /**
     * Mimic the cookie state of WebDriver (Defaults to true)
     * This will enable you to access files that are only available when logged in.
     * If set to false the connection will be made as an anonymouse user
     *
     * @param value
     */
    public void mimicWebDriverCookieState(boolean value) {
        this.mimicWebDriverCookieState = value;
    }

    /**
     * Load in all the cookies WebDriver currently knows about so that we can mimic the browser cookie state
     *
     * @param seleniumCookieSet
     * @return
     */
    private BasicCookieStore mimicCookieState(Set seleniumCookieSet) {
        BasicCookieStore mimicWebDriverCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        for (Cookie seleniumCookie : seleniumCookieSet) {
            BasicClientCookie duplicateCookie = new BasicClientCookie(seleniumCookie.getName(), seleniumCookie.getValue());
            duplicateCookie.setDomain(seleniumCookie.getDomain());
            duplicateCookie.setSecure(seleniumCookie.isSecure());
            duplicateCookie.setExpiryDate(seleniumCookie.getExpiry());
            duplicateCookie.setPath(seleniumCookie.getPath());
            mimicWebDriverCookieStore.addCookie(duplicateCookie);
        }

        return mimicWebDriverCookieStore;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the file/image download.
     *
     * @param element
     * @param attribute
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws NullPointerException
     */
    private String downloader(WebElement element, String attribute) throws IOException, NullPointerException, URISyntaxException {
        String fileToDownloadLocation = element.getAttribute(attribute);
        if (fileToDownloadLocation.trim().equals("")) throw new NullPointerException("The element you have specified does not link to anything!");

        URL fileToDownload = new URL(fileToDownloadLocation);
        File downloadedFile = new File(this.localDownloadPath + fileToDownload.getFile().replaceFirst("/|\\\\", ""));
        if (downloadedFile.canWrite() == false) downloadedFile.setWritable(true);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        LOG.info("Mimic WebDriver cookie state: " + this.mimicWebDriverCookieState);
        if (this.mimicWebDriverCookieState) {
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mimicCookieState(this.driver.manage().getCookies()));
        }

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(fileToDownload.toURI());
        HttpParams httpRequestParameters = httpget.getParams();
        httpRequestParameters.setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, this.followRedirects);
        httpget.setParams(httpRequestParameters);

        LOG.info("Sending GET request for: " + httpget.getURI());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget, localContext);
        this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        LOG.info("HTTP GET request status: " + this.httpStatusOfLastDownloadAttempt);
        LOG.info("Downloading file: " + downloadedFile.getName());
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getEntity().getContent(), downloadedFile);
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();

        String downloadedFileAbsolutePath = downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        LOG.info("File downloaded to '" + downloadedFileAbsolutePath + "'");

        return downloadedFileAbsolutePath;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's the difference between using `wget` and a system command to rename a file and what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

```
 String s = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#navbtm img")).getAttribute("src");
                    URL url = new URL(s);
                    System.out.println(url);
                    BufferedImage bufImgOne = ImageIO.read(url);
                    ImageIO.write(bufImgOne, "png", new File("test.png"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found an excellent article about it. Tried, and works perfectly:

http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

UPDATE:

Better solution is to get the image from the browser itself:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/8atiPIh39OY/Gp9_KEXnpRUJ