# Programmatically downloading a file using Selenium (version 2.46 and higher)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The `FileDownloader class` provided on the question below worked fine until I upgraded to `selenium 2.46`:

[Programmatically downloading a file using Selenium in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389734/programmatically-downloading-a-file-using-selenium-in-java)

When I run the same test with `selenium 2.46`, I now get redirected to the login page. Did anyone else face this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't storing the cookies.  Have a look at the original article, specifically the mimic cookie state parts: http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/.  It's also in my book Mastering Selenium WebDriver with a slightly updated implementation.  You can get the book here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mastering-Selenium-WebDriver-Mark-Collin/dp/1784394351

Answer (score 0):

The [Selenide project](http://selenide.org/) has a great, really well thought out, download helper in it.  I would investigate that, either as an example, or possibly actually using it.

```
$.download()
```